# Pagination Doesn't work with wordpress custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Pagination Doesn't work with word press custom post.
 i have tried these code below,but pagination doesn't appear.
tried different query but no result.
i am new in php and word press.i just copy and past code.
can anyone please help me?
what i have done so far are below.

in function.php

```
/*pagination*/  

function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {

    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_query;

    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";

    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }

    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";

}
```

in custom post query

```
<?php
                            global $post;
                            $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type'=> 'latestnews');
                            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                            foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 
                        ?>
                        <div class="page_news">
                        <div class="single_page_news">
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?><h2>
                            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                        <?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Use These code

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') :1;
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1,'paged' => $paged,'post_type' => 'achievements','orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
```

endwhile;

Instead of

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type'=> 'latestnews');
 $myposts = get_posts( $args );
```

Follow this link
http://thenetapp.com/2014/01/how-to-list-wordpress-posts-with-pagination/

Comment: Thanks Yatendra.Instead of which code should i use that code?

Comment: Never use `query_posts`. Never

Comment: Sorry that is not working.instead of custom post it shows default post. code i used is below         <?php
global $post;
$paged = (get_query_var(‘paged’)) ? get_query_var(‘paged’) : 1;
$args = array(
‘posts_per_page’ => 3,
‘paged’ => $paged,
‘post_type’=>'latestnews'
);

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
       foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 
      ?>
      <div class="page_news">
      <div class="single_page_news">
       <h2><?php the_title(); ?><h2>
       <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Your pagination function is only set up for the default main query, not for a custom query.

Also, don't use `get_posts` for paginated queries. It it is nice function to use for a custom query, but it becomes a bummer to work with once you require pagination.

Rather use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for paginated queries, it is much easier to use.

Example:

```
$paged = (get_query_var(‘paged’)) ? get_query_var(‘paged’) :  1;

$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'post_type' => 'YOUR POST TYPE'
);

$q = new WP_Query($args);

if($q->have_post()) {
   while($q->have_posts()) {
     $q->the_post();

     //YOUR LOOP

   }
  //YOUR PAGINATION
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

You can have a look at the codex for extra parameters.

You now need to change every instance of `$wp_query` in your pagination function to `$q` for it to work.

Just a point of note, you don't have to call the `$post` global

**EDIT**

From your comments, there is a much easier way to accomplish your goal without any custom query

This page is an archive page that is meant to display your custom post type `latestnews`. You can simply just rename your `archive-custom.php` to `archive-latestnews.php`. See the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy). Just make sure `has_archive` is set to `true` when you register your post type

You should also never shop the main query for a custom query on any type of archive page. It is always troublesome, as you can see. So, delete your custom query and replace it with the default query

This is all you should have in your archive page

```
if(have_post()) {
   while(have_posts()) {
     the_post();

     //YOUR LOOP

   }
  //YOUR PAGINATION
}
```

Just change all the instances of `$q` back to `$wp_query` again. Everything should work then

For extra info, you have to check out [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/155976/31545) I've done on WPSE

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by no result yet. Are you getting any errors? Have you turned debug on?

Comment: Thank you pieter. Actually pagination displays but when I click on 2nd page it doesn't work

Comment: By doesn't work, do you mean you get a 404 page or do you get the same posts over and over when you page?

Comment: Also, did you make sure to change all `$wp_query` to `$q`. Is this a normal page, or is it set a explicitely as frontpage

Comment: Thanks pieter. It displays 404 not found

Comment: It is archive-custom.php page.

Comment: Thank you. I hope this solves your problem. If it does, don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer

Comment: Can you please help me?. I am totally frustrated with a problem regarding wordpress. I am new in WordPress. 
What i want. ....
I have a custom post type(actually 3) and from that custom post type one post will show in home page., and below that post there is a link. When visitors will click on that link, it will take them in a page where all posts of that custom post type will show with pagination.

Comment: What i have done so far. ...
Created custom post type. Called one post in home page.( Upto that it's working fine. ) created a archive-custom. Php file. 
But couldn't solve that link. Php the permalink doesn't work. 
Also if I try to access the archive page by mysite.com/archive-custom.Php no post shows there. 
Search in Google, wordpress codex . But unfortunately ended up with no result. Can anyone Please help me ?

Comment: Please read my answer carefully please. I've explained whet you should do

Comment: Wordpress follows a strict template hierarchy, and if you do any thing outside that hierarchy, it is simply ignored. That is your problem as explained. As it stands with your current setup, pagination will never work. Wordpress will keep on ignoring what you want to do because it goes against normal hierarchy